# Best Practice? Casting chars as bytes

Tags: java, encryption, casting, char, byte

I have been working on an encryption program, utilizing a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) and [Xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).  I have done a fair bit of research on the topic and looked for answers to my question, but if I have missed any, feel free to tell me in the comments. Basically I have been converting the input text files into `BufferReaders` and from there I have been creating a string for each line of the document. I am then utilizing the one-time pad of n characters and using the lines:

```
for(int x=0;x<stringLine.length()-1;x++){
        byte z= (byte) (stringLine.charAt(x)^oTP.get(y));
```

`y` is unimportant to the actual problem but it tracks the overall index of the one-time pad, through every usage (encrypting multiple .txt files with the same pad) and throughout every line.

I also use a similiar casting technique, but instead from bytes to their raw char representation here:

```
for (int x=0; x<bit.size(); x++){
       for (int q=0; q<bit.get(x).size(); q++){
              outF.print((char) (bit.get(x).get(q)).byteValue());
```

`bit` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Byte>>`, which contains multiple `ArrayList<Byte>`, with each index representing the encrypted byte for each character on a line. `outF` is just a simple `PrintWriter` for writing the encrypted file.

This has all just been context for my final question which is: Is casting from `byte` to `char` and vice versa the best way to approach this? If my desired output is the ASCII representation for each byte, not just the numerical representation, is this the **best** and **most efficient** way to accomplish that?

The program seems to be working so far, but I'm not sure it is working as I'd like it to.

Thanks in advance for any help and/or advice.

Comment: In today's Unicode world what guarantee is there your approach will work at all? How will you convert a 32-bit Unicode CodePoint into a 7 bit byte? Your solution needs to use the various encoders to convert a string into bytes. Those encoders are Unicode aware and will help you.

Comment: If you cast a `char` to a `byte` you throw away the top half of the `char`.  This doesn't matter for standard ASCII characters, but will cause you to corrupt many characters in non-English text, as well as line-drawing characters, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks, what do you mean the "top half?" If at the moment I am just interested in encoding english-only text, should it behave that way?

Comment: A Java `char` is 16 bits.  A `byte` is 8 bits.  A `char` doesn't fit into a `byte`.

Comment: so how do you recommend I keep intact all 16 bits of the `char`?

Comment: Don't cast it to byte.  If you want a byte array from a String, use one of the `getBytes` methods of String.  Generally you *should not* specify an ASCII charset for the conversion, as that will simply drop the high-order bytes the same as a cast.  Rather, if you have n0 reason to do otherwise, use "UTF-8", as it's the most general translation between chars and bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, casting `char` to `byte` is not a good practice. To convert text to a string of bytes, you should use a `Charset`, or another API, which provides a well-known character-to-byte encoding. For example:

```
byte[] encoded = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

The same applies for decoding bytes to text:

```
String str = new String(buf, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

However, based on the description of your application, you shouldn't be converting to text at all. Use something like this:

```
static void encrypt(InputStream is, OneTimePad otp, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
  long index = 0;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  while (true) {
    int n = is.read(buffer);
    if (n < 0)
      break;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      buffer[i] ^= otp.get(index++);
    os.write(buffer, 0, n);
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I looked at charset, but I decided that I preferred to work `ArrayLists`, not arrays, just because its difficult to know the size of the document and of each line beforehand. I'll take another look at `Charset` though and come back.

Comment: @Wold there's no need to know the size of the document or each line beforehand. In fact, if you are working with streams, you shouldn't convert to text at all. Just read chunks of data into a byte[], encrypt the array in-place, and write the result to another stream. This is obviously more efficient in time and space, but it's also much more secure, because you aren't splattering immutable copies of the plain text all over the heap to be paged out to disk in unencrypted form.

Comment: ,the `OneTimePad` object can just be an array of characters right, or are you referencing a java class included in `util`? Also this is able to deal with reading characters and not concatenating the 2nd half of the 16 byte `char` right? THanks for you help so far.

Comment: You could use an array of bytes instead of `OneTimePad`. I wasn't sure what the type of the variable `oTP` is in your question, so I was just making something up to illustrate. Why are you hung up on characters? Encryption operates on bytes, not characters. It doesn't matter what the bytes represent. In fact, if it made a difference, that would be a big hint that your encryption is leaking information about the encrypted data. So, I don't understand your question about concatenating halves of chars. Bits are bits.